# application of wavelet to vibration signal

Tags: signal-analysis

I ask you to help me to interpret this figure corresponding to a diagnosis of gear failure using CWT (Haar);
[image]I have already worked on the analysis of the vibratory signals using the FFT; But since the signals from the bearings and the gears are non-stationary it is considered necessary to apply WT. So I started with simulated signals of gear failures to evaluate the sensitivity of this method compared to that of Fourrier

Comment: Thank you for your help and for the video. My problem is not to understand the principle of wavelets but especially to interpret them.
For example in the figure I didn't know  to indicate that the gear is defective ?!

Comment: Since the signal is oscillatory, Haar may not be the best choice. You could try higher-order complex wavelets, and display the phase scalogram as well. Then, you can start comparing displays for both a nicely working and a failing one. What kind on failure are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this area for a while. The wavelet transform is a more powerful tool for time-frequency (TF) & feature extraction since the FFT or STFT always suffers from the resolution issues in TF domain. As a starter, I think the short videos provided in MATLAB is a very good point to start with. I paste the 1st part here and you can also find the rest parts from it.

https://www.mathworks.com/videos/understanding-wavelets-part-1-what-are-wavelets-121279.html

Bests,
GL

Comment: I think these video can help you understand this figure. Anyway, the major difference between FFT and CWT is that FFT is frequency domain based study and CWT is time-frequency domain based study. In your problem, the gear failure will lead to a frequency change/nonlinearity, and with the two coefficients in your second plot, you can localize when the failure occurs in the time domain. Detailed explanation for these two coefficients are in the videos.